# Discord.NET How can I give every person a role by one command?

Tags: c#, discord, roles, discord.net

How can I give to every person on the server a specific role just by one command?

Comment: I'm new to Discord.NET, so i don't know how to write that part of code properly, I tried to find info, but didn't find anything.

Comment: My mistake, misread the tags and was thinking of another discord library.

Comment: Break the problem down into its parts.  Find out how to loop over all the members of the server, and find out how to add a role to a member.  Then combine those together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the code below. There are various ways of improving the command's functionality so perhaps think about that.

```
[Command("addrole all"), Summary("Adds the Star role to all users")]
public async Task AddRoleStarCommand()
{
    // Gets all the users of the guild. Note that this may not completely
    // work for extremely large guilds (thousands of users).
    var users = await Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync();

    // Gets the role "Star".
    var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Star");

    // Adds the role "Star" to each user in the guild.
    foreach (IGuildUser user in users)
    { 
        await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
    }
}
```

Remember that in order to use `GetUsersAsync()`, you need an `IGuild`, not a `SocketGuild`.

```
public async Task SocketGuildDemoCommand()
{
    // Don't do this.
    // Does not exist, error returned.
    SocketGuild guild = Context.Guild;
    var users = await guild.GetUsersAsync();
}

public async Task IGuildDemoCommand()
{
    // Do this.
    // Exists, should work perfectly.
    IGuild guild = Context.Guild;
    var users = await guild.GetUsersAsync();
}
```

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Discord.NET, so I really don't know where i can use `GetUsersAsync()`, and there's nothing about it in documentation.

Comment: @Niko I understand. I have edited my message and provided the solution. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried `var users = await Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync();` and I'm having error on `GetUsersAsync()` part, it says: *'SocketGuiId' does not contain a definition for 'GetUsersAsync' and no accessible extension method 'GetUsersAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'SocketGuiId' could be found*

Comment: I see, that is a strange error. Not that there is a typo in your error: "SocketGuiId" contains a capital "I" instead of a lowercase "l". They both look identical which is confusing.

Please see my edit on my post and tell me if that clarifies anything for you. @Niko

Comment: Yeah, that error is gone now, but now I'm having another one when I'm trying to start the bot.
On `static void Main(string[] args) => new main().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
It says: **System.InvalidOperationException: 'No type reader found for type IGuild, one must be specified'**

*I am sorry if it's dumb error which is fixing by adding one string in code, I'm just new to all of that.*

Comment: Can you send me your main code? The part that starts the bot. Through GitHub or Hastebin or something.

Comment: Does your command class inherit `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>`? @Niko

Comment: Yes, i have it there.

Comment: @Niko I have made another edit to my post in the second command block. Please see if the second method works.

Comment: Yeah, just tried that, now it works fine. Thank you so much, you really helped me instead of giving -rep to my question like others did, have a nice day ;)

Comment: If you have a `SocketGuild`, simply do `guild.Users`....there is no need to cast it to an `IGuild` just to use `GetUsersAsync` instead.